# If Statement Only Executing Else Part

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

I have a simple program that validates a sign up form. Basically I reach a problem when one of my "if" statements can only execute the "else" part. If I change the form so that "if" is executed, nothing happens. Below is my code:

```
function verifyprocedure() {
    var originalpassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var checkpassword = document.getElementById("verifypassword").value;
    var emailcheck = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var male = document.getElementById("gendermale");
    var female = document.getElementById("genderfemale");
    var form = document.getElementById("signup");
    var emailexist = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    if (originalpassword == checkpassword) {
        if (originalpassword.length < 9) {
            if (emailexist.test(emailcheck)) //this is the statement that does not work
            {
                alert("Hello World!"); //this is whats supposed to be executed
            } else { //this is successfully executed
                $("#email").notify("Please enter a valid email address.");
            }
        } else {
            $("#password").notify("Passwords must have at least 9 characters.");
        }

    } else {
        $("#verifypassword").notify("Passwords do not match.");
    }
}
```

Comment: --Which if are we talking about here?-- nevermind saw the comment just now

Comment: you don't really need all that nesting, do you? in particular, why condition the email on the password? it appears you can display many notifications at once, so there's no need to try to whittle a path for every combination...

Comment: Please tell us what input you tested this with. What is `emailcheck`?

Comment: its a radio input and emailcheck is to test email validation

Comment: Sidenote: If you are anyways using jQuery then why to use plain javascript. You can anyways do 

`var originalpassword = $("password").val();` instead of 
`var originalpassword = document.getElementById("password").value;`

Answer (score 1):

Did you check whether it is working or not ?

anyway it is working for me,i think your input should be invalid you can use the following code for checking

```
 var originalpassword ="abcdefgh";
    var checkpassword = "abcdefgh";
    var emailcheck = "arun@gmail.com";
    var male ="male";


    var emailexist = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    if (originalpassword == checkpassword) {
      alert("hai");
}

  if (originalpassword.length < 9) {
       if (emailexist.test(emailcheck)) 
            {
                alert("Hello World!"); 
            } else { 
              alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
            }

  }
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jf8n16hj/)**

**UPDATE**

```
    var originalpassword ="abcdefgh";
    var checkpassword = "abcdefgh";
    var emailcheck = "arun@gmail.com";
    var male ="male";

    var emailexist = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    if (originalpassword == checkpassword) 
    {
      alert("hai");
              if (originalpassword.length > 9)
          {
               if (emailexist.test(emailcheck)) 
                {
                alert("Hello World!"); 
                } 
              else
              { 
              alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
                }

          }
         else
             {
           alert("Passwords must have at least 9 characters.");
            }

    }
else {
       alert("Passwords do not match.");
    }
```

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/263qmxy2/)** It will satisfy all conditions.

Note : Check your if condition for password length, if you want the desired output then it will be like  `if (originalpassword.length > 9)`

Comment: then where is your problem in your code you are mentioned that this part is not working and i think in my code it is working

Comment: all of mine are satisfied except for the email one

Comment: @LeuvenWang what is the problem with email ? tell me if you are facing anyproblem

Comment: @LeuvenWang i think your password validatiion is also working fine , provide a password minimum 9 character and give an invalid password it will alert an error message

Comment: i used your fiddle on my computer but it dosen't work

Comment: @LeuvenWang i had checked the example and it is perfectly working , anyway which browser you are using ? ie ? , and where is the problem occurs , i mean which part does not execute ?

Comment: oh wait i fixed it. turns out my sister deleted the part which calls the function. lol sorry for the time taken. and thanks for the support.

Comment: It's  ok, happy to help you .

Answer (score 0):

```
if (originalpassword.length > 9) {
            if (emailexist.test(emailcheck)) //this is the statement that does not work
            {
                alert("Hello World!"); //this is whats supposed to be executed
            } else { //this is successfully executed
                $("#email").notify("Please enter a valid email address.");
            }
        } else {
            $("#password").notify("Passwords must have at least 9 characters.");
        }
```